# Not able to view server-status

Tags: proxy, apache-httpd, tomcat

My application is deployed on ROOT folder in tomcat and it is connected to apache using proxy.
Ex:-

```
ProxyPass / ajp://192.168.0.xx:8011/
ProxyPassReverse / ajp://192.168.0.xx:8011/
```

When I fire http://test.com/server-status it gives blank page and I receive below error in access.log

```
MY IP - - [03/Apr/2014:17:09:48 +0530] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36"
```

But if I deploy my application on another directory, say Test, in tomcat and using below proxy setting in Apache

```
ProxyPass /Test ajp://192.168.0.xxx:8011/Test
ProxyPassReverse /Test ajp://192.168.0.xxx:8011/Test/
```

And now if I hit the url: http://test.com/server-status then it shows me the server page with status of server.

Below is my server-status configuration

```
<Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Satisfy any
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Please let me know how to use server-status with deploying application as ROOT in tomcat.

Comment: Can you try the following? Stop Tomcat, delete your ROOT directory, rename your app as ROOT.war and restart tomcat.

Answer (score 2):

The `/server-status` page is a feature of Apache, not Tomcat. When you setup your `ProxyPass` rules at the top level of your URL, i.e. `/`, all traffic, including `/server-status`, is being forwarded to your Tomcat server, which doesn't serve a page at `/server-status`, hence the 404 being reported by Apache.

You can tell Apache *NOT* to proxy traffic that's bound for `/server-status` by adding your rules like so:

```
ProxyPass /server-status !
ProxyPass /Test ajp://192.168.0.xxx:8011/Test
ProxyPassReverse /Test ajp://192.168.0.xxx:8011/Test/
```

You can read more about this feature in the official Apache docs.

> The ! directive is useful in situations where you don't want to reverse-proxy a subdirectory

#### References

- [Apache ProxyPass Directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass)

Answer (score 0):

You can add "ProxyPass !" to the location section. The result should look like this.

```
<Location /server-status>
    ProxyPass !
    SetHandler server-status
    Order deny,allow
    Satisfy any
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

Comment: Welcome to U&L. We generally like our answers to be long form here and to explain what they're doing or how they work. Code drops or configuration drops such as this are discouraged.